# Sorting Using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

What is the best way to implement sorting using XSLT?

**Input:** `<cross-refs>5,8,4,3,9</cross-refs>`

**Excepted output:**  `<cross-refs>3,4,5,8,9</cross-refs>`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:template match="cross-refs">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of separator=",">
            <xsl:perform-sort select="tokenize(., ',')">
                <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number"/>
            </xsl:perform-sort>
        </xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Note that this assumes you want to sort in numerical, not alphabetical, order.

---

In XSLT 3.0 you could reduce this to:

```
<xsl:template match="cross-refs">
    <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:value-of select="sort(tokenize(., ',')!xs:integer(.))" separator=","/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```